# error while inflating class android.support.v7.widget.CardView

Tags: android, android-cardview, layout-inflater, backwards-compatibility, appcompatactivity

we already have a bunch of similar question to this but all of them was related to backward compatibility or they are on eclipse  (as far i understand) but i think problem is occurring while inflating the `cardView` class it was working fine on my emulator (SDK 23) but when am trying it on my  other emulator (SDK 19) am getting this error and the error is pointing me to this line :

```
    @Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolderImpl(ViewGroup viewGroup, final ParallaxRecyclerAdapter<Information> adapter, int i) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService( Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
    return new ViewHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, viewGroup, false)); // this line

}
```

i also tried `getActvity().inflate.....` instead as above mentioned   but still the same error exists  , i also checked my gradle , everything seems fine here :

```
dependencies {

compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
compile 'com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:2.1.1'
compile 'com.isseiaoki:simplecropview:1.0.16'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
compile('com.github.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.8.5.3@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
```

my error :

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.CardView
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:621)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:697)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:756)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
at pb.myPackage.FeedFragment$3.onCreateViewHolderImpl(FeedFragment.java:689)
at com.poliveira.parallaxrecyclerview.ParallaxRecyclerAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(ParallaxRecyclerAdapter.java:132)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5482)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4707)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4617)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:1994)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1390)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1353)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:574)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3028)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:2906)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3283)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
at android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.onLayout(SwipeRefreshLayout.java:596)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1055)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onLayout(ViewPager.java:1695)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1055)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.layoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:1091)
at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:801)
at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:815)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:
```

any clue whats going wrong here ??

XML :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:paddingLeft="4dp"
android:paddingRight="4dp"
android:paddingBottom="2dp">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:id="@+id/cardview"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
    card_view:cardElevation="2dp"
    card_view:cardMaxElevation="2dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">



....here i have a bunch of other layout elements
         </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>



</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: LogCat says :"Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.CardView", it means there is an error in the XML file line 10. Post your XML code so that we can assist you better

Comment: @RakshitNawani please check the updated question

Comment: Can you tell me what is line 10 in your XML as the XML is not the whole code

Comment: @RakshitNawani line 10 =   `<android.support.v7.widget.CardView`

Comment: did you add card_view in the main tag ?

Comment: what is main tag ? sorry am new here do you mean just after the parent Layout ?

Comment: <android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="4dp">

I was talking about "  xmlns:card_view"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116135/discussion-between-rakshit-nawani-and-remy-boys).

Comment: did that help you anyway ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this it will help you 
remove this   android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:paddingLeft="4dp"
android:paddingRight="4dp"
android:paddingBottom="2dp">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/cardview"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
    card_view:cardElevation="2dp"
    card_view:cardMaxElevation="2dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">



....here i have a bunch of other layout elements
         </RelativeLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>



</LinearLayout>
```