# Recycler view adapter InflateException

Tags: android, xml, android-recyclerview, adapter

I'm getting crash reports from the Google Play Dev Console due to "InflateException" when I'm inflating a card in my adapters "onCreateViewHolder", but I can't seem to find the source of the issue. Here is the stack trace from the dev console:

[image: stack trace]

Here is the method that is causing the crash:

```
@Override
    public HeatmapDataViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        //there was a crash report (InflateException) while inflating this view, but I can't seem to find the issue?
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_heatmap, parent, false);
        HeatmapDataViewHolder heatmapDataViewHolder = new HeatmapDataViewHolder(listener, v);

        return heatmapDataViewHolder;
    }
```

I have read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38132148/error-while-inflating-class-android-support-v7-widget-cardview) that the issue could be with `android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"`, but I can't find any reason why this would be the issue. Even if it is the issue, how will I get the ripple effect on the card view?

Here is the xml that I'm trying to inflate:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
    android:background="@color/light_gray"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:clickable="true">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="4">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

                <com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/card_image_view"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                    app:riv_corner_radius="2dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/test_bkg"/>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="left|bottom"
                    android:background="@android:drawable/screen_background_dark_transparent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:paddingLeft="14dp"
                    android:paddingRight="12dp"
                    android:paddingTop="8dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="8dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/title_text_view"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="18dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:text="Title"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/subtitle_text_view"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="12dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:text="Sub Title"/>

                </LinearLayout>
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center|right"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:paddingRight="8dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/delete_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="@dimen/icon_padding"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_delete_black_24dp"
                android:tint="@color/dark_gray"
                android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"    />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/edit_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="@dimen/icon_padding"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_edit_black_24dp"
                android:tint="@color/dark_gray"
                android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"    />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/share_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="@dimen/icon_padding"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_share_black_24dp"
                android:tint="@color/dark_gray"
                android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"    />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/view_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="@dimen/icon_padding"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_view_24dp"
                android:tint="@color/dark_gray"
                android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"    />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Share the code of HomeAdapter class.

Comment: Oh yea sorry, meant to include that. I added it to the post

Answer (score 0):

Pass the context to the adapter and then Change your this line of code

```
View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
.inflate(R.layout.card_heatmap, parent, false);
```

To

```
 View v = LayoutInflater.from(context_passed_to_adapter)
.inflate(R.layout.card_heatmap, parent, false);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Let me know if that helps.

Comment: The RecyclerView.Adapter does not have a "getContext()" method, that's why I have to use the ViewGroup parent.

I'm going to try passing the context to the adapter in the constructor and use that to inflate the view. I'll see if that changes anything

Comment: Yeah you literally changed the answer to what I just said.

Comment: Yup. Hope that helps. Your exception was not of the xml or foreground you are using but of the context :)

Comment: @swerly Any luck ?

Comment: I'm not sure yet. I couldn't replicate the issue, but I made that change and pushed a new version of my app to the store so I'll just have to see if crash reports show it was fixed

Comment: Change context source helps?

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here.

```
        <ImageButton
...
            android:background="?selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
...
```

Had to change from getApplicationContext to parent.getContext().

```
@Override
public ListNameRVAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType){
    //View v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.recycler_cardview_item_list_names,parent,false);
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_cardview_item_list_names,parent,false);

    ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
    return vh;
}
```